# Are questions asking to identify particular motor vehicle on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Since you're focused on engines, maintenance and repair -- probably not, but I'd like to clarify.

I'd like to post a photo of a car, I spotted and ask, what kind of vehicle is this (manufacturer model, maybe get some tech specs).

I *might* try to foul you, that I'm trying to identify this car, because I need to buy a spare parts for its engine. :> But, no one is going to believe me, right? :>

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that was more a question for the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop)...

Answer (score 1):

I have personally answered vehicle ID questions before on a 67 Camaro. While it could become tedious very quickly, I'm not seeing a real reason for it to be off-topic. The chat would work as well, as @NickC suggested.

I don't think you'd fool anyone with your example question, btw. If you don't know which vehicle you have, you shouldn't be working on it :-)

Comment: LOL! :> It's not, that I don't know which vehicle _I have_. It's that I don't know what is exact model of the vehicle, _I would like to have_. In other words -- I saw a car on a street today, while driving and immediately felt in love with it. But, since I'm motor industry newbie / ignorant, I didn't managed to figure out, what this car is. My on-board camera captured it (though photos have quite low quality) and this inspired me to write this question. However, before you have actually answered, my friends managed to identify this car. So, this particular discussion is over. Thanks.

Comment: @trejder ... I wasn't suggesting you didn't know what kind of car you have. What I was suggesting is if a person were to ask a question like that, that is what I'd think in the process. I'm glad you figured out what the car was you were looking at ... makes life a whole lot easier :P